# attach the unique id with the URL cross entire app in Laravel

Tags: laravel, url, routes

I have created an application like a portfolio, every user has a unique id or username, I need to generate a copy of this for each user by adding the ID in the URL as a parameter, I know how to do that surly, but I need to attach only with the one Route and then it will still across entire pages and requests for this user? is there any way to do that?

I think I can do it in this way, and then I will store it in the session? is it possible? and is it the best way, because I need the official or professional way

```
Route::get('/uid', [HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
```

Comment: do you mean like http://localhost/UID/any_application_routes_onward as an example anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assuse you want to have theese routes for example

```
/{uid}/profile
/{uid}/prot
```

Based on [document](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-prefixes) you can use group to add prefix to all the routes

```php
Route::prefix('/{uid}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [HomeController::class, 'profile'])->name('profile');
    Route::get('/prot', [HomeController::class, 'prot'])->name('prot');
});
```

Using this you can pass uid across all routes that created in this groups